# Apache Deltaspike @Configproperty not working with Jakarta EE10 / Wildfly 27 Final

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, deltaspike

I am using Apache Deltaspike to handle environment specific properties.

Stack:
Wildfly 27 final
Java 17
Jakarta EE10

An Example of how i use it is listed below

`

```
@RequestScoped
public class KbMaxConnector {


    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "kbmax.url")
    @Default
    private String url;
    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "kbmax.email")
    @Default
    private String email;
    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "kbmax.password")
    @Default
    private String password;
    @Inject
    private Logger LOGGER;

    public KBMaxModelsQuote getQuote(Integer quoteId) throws ApiException {
        LOGGER.debug("Calling KbMax quote api with quoteId: {}, on url:{} user: {} password: {}",quoteId,url,email,password);
        QuotesApi quotesApi = new QuotesApi(url, email, password);
        return quotesApi.apiQuotesByIdGet(quoteId);
    }


}
```

The values for url, email and password are different for the different environments. This has been working like a charm, for many years.`

However when i now try to move to Jakarta EE10 it has stopped working.
Sample stack trace below.

Thankful for input

`

```
rg.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type float with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @ConfigProperty private com.scanreco.cms.control.generator.pdf.MountingPdfGenerator.frontPageMiniImageScale
  at com.scanreco.cms.control.generator.pdf.MountingPdfGenerator.frontPageMiniImageScale(MountingPdfGenerator.java:0)
WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
  - Producer Method [Float] with qualifiers [@Any @ConfigProperty] declared as [[UnbackedAnnotatedMethod] @Dependent @Produces @ConfigProperty protected io.smallrye.config.inject.ConfigProducer.produceFloatConfigProperty(InjectionPoint)]

        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:367)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:285)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:141)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:162)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:515)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
        at org.jboss.weld.core@5.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Exception 8 :
```

`

Se above

It is the @inject of  @Configproperty that fails

Comment: I don't think DeltaSpike works with Jakarta EE 10.  However, it looks to me like you're using the MicroProfile Config.

Comment: That is the conclusion that i also drew, it does however with Jakarta EE9.1

Comment: May I ask how you get Deltaspike to work with Jakarta EE9.1? 
I notice that at least Deltaspike 1.9.6 depends on javax.* classes and not Jakarta.* classes.

Answer (score 1):

SmallRye Config (from your stack trace) implements MicroProfile Config specification, so the @ConfigProperty you need to use is [org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-config/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/eclipse/microprofile/config/inject/ConfigProperty.java).

I'm not aware of any integration with Deltaspike, but if you need to use it, you need to have something on the classpath that provides injection with the ConfigProperty qualifier coming from Deltaspike. The error says that the only injection point that provides the correct type comes from SmallRye Config.

Comment: Deltaspike works just fine on Jakarta EE 9.1 but stopped so in EE 10.

The eclipse one is not what i need as i use the Project Stage feature from Deltaspike

Comment: Then I recommend sticking to WFLY 26.1.x releases until Deltaspike moves to Jakarta 10.

Comment: Thank you. However we needed the move so i cut Deltaspike out.

I appreciate your input though.